# what's a clean and efficient way of connecting objects to each other

Tags: c++

Feels like a question that has been asked before but I'm not exactly sure how to properly word it in a google search. Say I have a MainWindow object and in that object I define several objects PanelA, PanelB, PanelC and PanelD. What's a good way of connecting these objects to each other without having constructors that look like this

`PanelA(PanelB* b, PanelC* c, PanelD* d)`

Would you suggest to just pass them all in through the main class like so

```
PanelA(MainWindow* mw)
{
    b=mw->b; c=mw->c; d=mw->d;
}
```

Or is there better ways to structure my classes. What's this problem known as in general, so that I can google this stuff myself.

Comment: How do they need to be connected? What is the purpose? Are they just exchanging data, calling each others' functions, ...? All these factors can influence your design.

Comment: How to realize such relations and connections is way more complicated than assumend in this naive question. One good example is the Qt Signal/Slot model, how such should be designed.

Comment: Are you talking about ownership models?

Comment: @UnholySheep In my case it is strictly exchanging data, though can you mention how both would lead to different design and which methods are preferred?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what is this general problem known as?

Comment: @c650 I have no idea, is that what this general problem is referred to as?

Comment: @anonymousnoob There's no _one word description_ for the problem AFAIK. It's a conglomerate of patterns to use for a good UI framework design.

Comment: It depends. Will you aways have 3 panels or an unlimited number? If you only have 3 no more no less then what you have is ok most probably if its more, maybe you want an addPanel function and internally store those in a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's this problem known as in general, so that I can google this stuff myself.

The design defect is known as *strong coupling* of types and use of hardcoded relations.

The general approach to refactor such code is to introduce *interfaces* and design patterns to solve the actual dependencies by means of functionality.